# What analysis should we use for repeated measures when some only have the first or second measure?

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, missing-data, ordinal-data

We're doing a report on a teacher rating system. It finished its second year and in the report we have the percentages of teachers that received each rating (ordinal variable with 4 levels) for each year. Our client asked if the differences were significant.

The issue we're having is that only about 75% of teachers were rated for both years. Additional schools were added the second year, some teachers left, some were hired, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a mixed ordinal model, e.g. check out `clmm` from R's `ordinal` package, with teacher as a random effect (grouping variable).  Unbalanced designs should be fine (but with max two observations per teacher you definitely might want to check out Gauss-Hermite quadrature/the `nAGQ` argument.  You might also want to add school as a random effect (although you will no longer be able to use Gauss-Hermite quadrature with this package).  The `MCMCglmm` package also allows an ordinal response.